# Why do I get this error when trying to archive the Security event log?

Tags: powershell, wmi, event-log, get-wmiobject

```bsh
$EventLog = Get-WmiObject Win32_NTEventlogFile -Filter "LogFileName = 'Security'"
$Date = Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd

$Path = "C:\Users\aamouss\Desktop\SecurityLogs"

$EventLog.BackupEventlog("$Path\$env:COMPUTERNAME`_Security_$Date.evt")

Clear-EventLog -LogName Security
```

I'm running the above script but getting the below error.

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
>   At line:6 char:1
>   + $EventLog.BackupEventlog("$Path\$env:COMPUTERNAME`*Security*$Date.evt ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Answer (score 2):

`$EventLog` is the only thing that could be `$null` in the line indicated by the error.  If I try executing the command that initializes `$EventLog`, I see it doesn't return anything...

```bsh
PS> Get-WmiObject Win32_NTEventlogFile -Filter "LogFileName = 'Security'"
PS>
```

If I remove the `-Filter` from that `Get-WmiObject` command, here's the logs I see on my Windows 10 system as a standard user...

```bsh
PS> Get-WmiObject Win32_NTEventlogFile

FileSize LogfileName            Name                                                        NumberOfRecords
-------- -----------            ----                                                        ---------------
15798272 Application            C:\WINDOWS\System32\Winevt\Logs\Application.evtx                      27698
   69632 HardwareEvents         C:\WINDOWS\System32\Winevt\Logs\HardwareEvents.evtx                       0
   69632 Internet Explorer      C:\WINDOWS\System32\Winevt\Logs\Internet Explorer.evtx                    0
   69632 Key Management Service C:\WINDOWS\System32\Winevt\Logs\Key Management Service.evtx               0
   69632 Parameters             C:\WINDOWS\System32\Winevt\Logs\Parameters.evtx                           0
   69632 State                  C:\WINDOWS\System32\Winevt\Logs\State.evtx                                0
14749696 System                 C:\WINDOWS\System32\Winevt\Logs\System.evtx                           24168
15732736 Windows PowerShell     C:\WINDOWS\System32\Winevt\Logs\Windows PowerShell.evtx               10470
```

...and as an elevated user...

```bsh
PS> Get-WmiObject Win32_NTEventlogFile

FileSize LogfileName            Name                                                        NumberOfRecords
-------- -----------            ----                                                        ---------------
15798272 Application            C:\WINDOWS\System32\Winevt\Logs\Application.evtx                      27698
   69632 HardwareEvents         C:\WINDOWS\System32\Winevt\Logs\HardwareEvents.evtx                       0
   69632 Internet Explorer      C:\WINDOWS\System32\Winevt\Logs\Internet Explorer.evtx                    0
   69632 Key Management Service C:\WINDOWS\System32\Winevt\Logs\Key Management Service.evtx               0
   69632 Parameters             C:\WINDOWS\System32\Winevt\Logs\Parameters.evtx                           0
20975616 Security               C:\WINDOWS\System32\Winevt\Logs\Security.evtx                         29714
   69632 State                  C:\WINDOWS\System32\Winevt\Logs\State.evtx                                0
14749696 System                 C:\WINDOWS\System32\Winevt\Logs\System.evtx                           24170
15732736 Windows PowerShell     C:\WINDOWS\System32\Winevt\Logs\Windows PowerShell.evtx               10477
```

Notice that the `Security` log is only available when the cmdlet is run elevated.  Therefore, if I run the original command as an elevated user, it is able to access the `Security` log...

```bsh
PS> Get-WmiObject Win32_NTEventlogFile -Filter "LogFileName = 'Security'"

FileSize LogfileName Name                                          NumberOfRecords
-------- ----------- ----                                          ---------------
20975616 Security    C:\WINDOWS\System32\Winevt\Logs\Security.evtx           29723
```

From [Event Logging Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/eventlog/event-logging-security)...

> The `Security` log is designed for use by the system. However, users can read and clear the `Security` log if they have been granted the `SE_SECURITY_NAME` privilege (the "manage auditing and security log" user right).